# Gradle Version error in Android Studio development (API v34)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried lots of ways to fix this problem:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.ApplicationVariantImpl.
```

but everytime it gives me the same error and I can't understand how I would fix it.

I tried to change the gradle versions in the "build.gradle.kts" but it doesn't help.

Here is the "build.gradle.kts" code:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android") version "1.9.0"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(34)

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.clavisverba"
        minSdkVersion(21)
        targetSdkVersion(34)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjvm-default=compatibility")
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.31"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += setOf("/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0") // Adjusted version for consistency
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2") // Adjusted version for consistency
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.5.4") // Adjusted version for consistency
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics:1.5.4") // Adjusted version for consistency
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.5.4") // Adjusted version for consistency
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.2")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.5.4") // Adjusted version for consistency
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.9.0") // Use the latest Kotlin version
}
```

This code should import all the neccesary libraries, as well as the latest Kotlin version as named in the notices near the codes. If 1.9.0 isn't the latest Kotlin version importable, this would explain it. I know that there is a version "8.5.0" of Kotlin but once importet it says that it would be an "unknown snapshot" of Kotlin. Maybe there is something wrong with the other Kotlin file, in which the version is saved too, but I dont really think so, here is the file anyway:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
}
```